# Invert selection in iTunes?

Tags: uti, itunes, macos

I converted many media files in iTunes to be suited to iPod.
Now I have all the selected files along with the converted files (unselected).

I now want to invert selection so I can easily delete all the old files. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they have different media types:

1. Order by Media Type
2. Select all files with the original media type
3. Delete them

If they have the same media type:

1. Create a playlist with the selected files
2. Create another playlist with both type of files
3. Create a smart playlist with two conditions:

   - playlist is "playlist from step 2"
   - playlist is not "playlist from step 1"
4. Delete content of smart playlist

Comment: What's media type? There is no such column in iTunes.

Comment: Try "Kind" and "Bit Rate" (or use the second solution)

Comment: thanks, you're the man.
Another question, is there a 'hidden' feature to show disk location of file as well without opening the file info (^I)?

Comment: Right click on a song/video, "Show in Finder" (or however it's called in the english version)

Comment: I know about this (It's *Show in Explorer* BTW), but I was looking to add a column that shows the  file path. I guess this feature doesn't exist, nevermind.

Comment: On the Mac I would have recommended a short AppleScript to copy the path into an unused metadata field but on the PC this won't help much... But as already mentioned somewhere else: If you let iTunes manage your library you can pretty much ignore physical paths anyway.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1431/discussion-between-patrix-and-shimmy)

Answer (score 0):

You can always sort by the check marks by clicking on the column header.  Once the checked songs and un-checked songs are grouped together, you can highlight the group you want to delete (click the first of that group then shift-click the last of that group) and hit the delete key.

This also moves the files to the recycle bin, so you can easily undo it if you get it wrong the first time.

Answer (score -1):

There is no invert selection option in iTunes.